# subimage shows when mainimage is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i want to make a toggle image like when i clicked the image the sub image will show up something like that... this is the image that has a toggle function..

```
<?php 
  include('../includes/inc.php');
  $user_id =json_decode($user->user_id);
  $albumname='';
  $album = $carousel->get_album($user_id);
  foreach ($album as $key => $myalbum) {
  $albumname = $myalbum['album_name'];

?>
  <div class="portfolio-image">
    <div  class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;">
    <img src="../assets/img/gallery/event-image3.jpg" style="display: block;margin: 0 auto; height:150px;width:200px;" data-id="<?php echo $myalbum['album_name']?>">
     <p style="text-align: center;"><strong><?php echo $myalbum['album_name'];?></strong></p>
     </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <p></p>
 </div>
<?php
 }
?>
```

this is where my function goes..

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on('click', 'img[data-id]', function () {
     var selected = $(this).attr('data-id');

     $ss = $('[data-id="' + selected +'"]').next('.picforalbum').toggle();

  });
</script>
```

this is where the sub image will show up. once that i clicked the image..

```
<div class="col-md-12 picforalbum">
 <?php

   include('../includes/inc.php');
   $user_id =json_decode($user->user_id);
   $album = $carousel->get_photoINalbum($albumname,$user_id);
  foreach ($album as $key => $pic) {
 ?>
  <div class="portfolio-image">
    <div  class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;">
    <img src="<?php echo $pic['photo'];?>" style="display: block;margin: 0 auto; height:150px;width:200px;" >
    </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <?php    
    }
  ?>

</div>
```

but the problem is when i tried to click the toggle image nothing happens...

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you want a toggle function for your image, I went ahead and built a simple [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atif_hassan/na0nds3w/). (As the picture takes a bit of time to load based on your net connection, please **wait for a few seconds** after clicking the image.)

What you need to do is basically call a function through ***onclick()*** on your image which changes the ***src*** attribute of your ***img*** tag. Thus if you maintain a boolean variable, you can easily alternate between true and false to change your image. So for true you'd have *link1* and for false you'd have *link2*.

**EDIT :** Since you said that the image should act as a toggle for "sub" images, I have edited the code wherein an image acts as a toggle for another image beside it. Check out the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atif_hassan/na0nds3w/) and code snippet below.

Here is a simple example.

```js
var toggle = false;

function toggle_img() {
  if (toggle) {
    document.getElementById("toggle_image").style.opacity = 0;
    toggle = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("toggle_image").style.opacity = 1;
    toggle = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="toggle" src="https://s19.postimg.org/an381cz4j/470766057_3f1e9a3933_b.jpg" alt="jungle" width="75vw" height="50vw" onclick="toggle_img()" />

<img id="toggle_image" src="https://s19.postimg.org/klo6nu8k3/sumatrantiger-002.jpg" alt="tiger" width="75vw" height="50vw" onclick="toggle_img()" style="opacity:0"/>
```

Comment: what im actually trying to achieve is that the image will be the toggle button and once i clicked the image sub images will show when i clicked it again it will hide.. something like that..

Comment: @LionSmith I have updated the code though, first of all, I really don't understand what "sub" images means and secondly "something like that" is not verbose enough. Either way, I believe that the code should serve as a good starting point for further changes, if required.